# Magento 2 - How to show related products in a thumbnail slider?

Tags: magento2, related-products, slider, up-sells

I want to show related products and/or products to upsell in a thumbnail slider on product page. I am using a child theme derived from Luma.

How should I achieve this? Is there anyway to integrate Flex slider in my theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my updated code.

```
<?php
switch ($type = $block->getType()) {

    case 'related-rule':
        if ($exist = $block->hasItems()) {
            $type = 'related';
            $class = $type;

            $image = 'related_products_list';
            $title = __('Related Products');
            $items = $block->getAllItems();
            $limit = $block->getPositionLimit();
            $shuffle = (int) $block->isShuffled();
            $canItemsAddToCart = $block->canItemsAddToCart();

            $showAddTo = false;
            $showCart = false;
            $templateType = null;
            $description = false;
        }
    break;

    case 'related':
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related $block */
        if ($exist = $block->getItems()->getSize()) {
            $type = 'related';
            $class = $type;

            $image = 'related_products_list';
            $title = __('Complete the Look');
            $items = $block->getItems();
            $limit = 0;
            $shuffle = 0;
            $canItemsAddToCart = $block->canItemsAddToCart();

            $showAddTo = true;
            $showCart = false;
            $templateType = null;
            $description = false;
        }
    break;

    case 'upsell-rule':
        if ($exist = $block->hasItems()) {
            $type = 'upsell';
            $class = $type;

            $image = 'upsell_products_list';
            $title = __('We found other products you might like!');
            $items = $block->getAllItems();
            $limit = $block->getPositionLimit();
            $shuffle = (int) $block->isShuffled();

            $showAddTo = false;
            $showCart = false;
            $templateType = null;
            $description = false;
            $canItemsAddToCart = false;
        }
    break;

    case 'upsell':
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Upsell $block */
        if ($exist = count($block->getItemCollection()->getItems())) {
            $type = 'upsell';
            $class = $type;

            $image = 'upsell_products_list';
            $title = __('You may also like');
            $items = $block->getItemCollection()->getItems();
            $limit = $block->getItemLimit('upsell');
            $shuffle = 0;

            $showAddTo = false;
            $showCart = false;
            $templateType = null;
            $description = false;
            $canItemsAddToCart = false;
        }
    break;

    case 'crosssell-rule':
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Crosssell $block */
        if ($exist = $block->hasItems()) {
            $type = 'crosssell';
            $class = $type;

            $image = 'cart_cross_sell_products';
            $title = __('More Choices:');
            $items = $block->getItemCollection();

            $showAddTo = true;
            $showCart = true;
            $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
            $description = false;
            $canItemsAddToCart = false;
        }
    break;

    case 'crosssell':
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Crosssell $block */
        if ($exist = count($block->getItems())) {
            $type = 'crosssell';
            $class = $type;

            $image = 'cart_cross_sell_products';
            $title = __('More Choices:');
            $items = $block->getItems();

            $showAddTo = true;
            $showCart = true;
            $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
            $description = false;
            $canItemsAddToCart = false;
        }
    break;

    case 'new':
        if ($exist = $block->getProductCollection()) {
            $type = 'new';
            $mode = 'grid';
            $type = $type . ' ' . $mode;

            $class = 'widget' . ' ' . $type;

            $image = 'new_products_content_widget_grid';
            $title = __('New Products');
            $items = $exist;

            $showAddTo = true;
            $showCart = true;
            $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
            $description = ($mode == 'list') ? true : false;
            $canItemsAddToCart = false;
        }
    break;

    case 'other':
    break;
}
?>

<?php if ($exist):?>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
    <?php if ($type == 'related' || $type == 'upsell'): ?>
        <?php if ($type == 'related'): ?>
            <div class="block <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $class ?>" data-mage-init='{"relatedProducts":{"relatedCheckbox":".related.checkbox"}}' data-limit="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $limit ?>" data-shuffle="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $shuffle ?>">
        <?php else: ?>
            <div class="block <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $class ?>" data-mage-init='{"upsellProducts":{}}' data-limit="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $limit ?>" data-shuffle="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $shuffle ?>">
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="block <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $class ?>">
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="block-title title">
        <strong id="block-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $class ?>-heading" role="heading" aria-level="2"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $title ?></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content content" aria-labelledby="block-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $class ?>-heading">
        <?php if ($type == 'related' && $canItemsAddToCart): ?>
        <div class="block-actions">
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Check items to add to the cart or') ?>
            <button type="button" class="action select" role="select-all"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('select all') ?></span></button>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="products wrapper grid products-grid products-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $type ?>">
            <div id="owlcarousel_<?=$type?>"  class="products list items product-items owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded">           
                <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
                <?php foreach ($items as $_item): ?>

                <?php $available = ''; ?>
                <?php if (!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable() && $type == 'related'): ?>
                    <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                        <?php $available = 'related-available'; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($type == 'related' || $type == 'upsell'): ?>
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ ($iterator++ == 1) ? '<div class="item product product-item" style="display: none;">' : '</div><div class="item product product-item" style="display: none;">' ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ ($iterator++ == 1) ? '<div class="item product product-item">' : '</div><div class="item product product-item">' ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="product-item-info <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $available ?>">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ '<!-- ' . $image . '-->' ?>
                    <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo">
                        <?= $block->getImage($_item, $image)->toHtml() ?>
                    </a>
                    <?php if ($type != 'related'): ?>
                    <div class="product details product-item-details">
                        <strong class="product name product-item-name"><a class="product-item-link" title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>">
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a>
                        </strong>

                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($_item) ?>
                        <?php if ($type == 'upsell'): ?>
                <div data-block="minicart" class="minicart-wrapper">
                    <a class="action showcart" href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>"></a>
                </div><?php endif; ?>

                            <?php if ($templateType): ?>
                                <?//= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, $templateType) ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php if ($canItemsAddToCart && !$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable() && $type == 'related'): ?>
                                <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                                    <div class="field choice related">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox related" id="related-checkbox<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>" name="related_products[]" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>" />
                                        <label class="label" for="related-checkbox<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span></label>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php if ($showAddTo || $showCart): ?>
                                <!--<div class="product actions product-item-actions">
                                    <?php if ($showCart): ?>
                                        <div class="actions-primary">
                                            <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                                                <?php if ($_item->getTypeInstance()->hasRequiredOptions($_item)): ?>
                                                    <button class="action tocart primary" data-mage-init='{"redirectUrl": {"url": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>"}}' type="button" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                                                        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                    </button>
                                                <?php else: ?>
                                                    <?php $postDataHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper');
                                                    $postData = $postDataHelper->getPostData($block->getAddToCartUrl($_item), ['product' => $_item->getEntityId()])
                                                    ?>
                                                    <button class="action tocart primary"
                                                            data-post='<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $postData ?>'
                                                            type="button" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                                                        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                    </button>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            <?php else: ?>
                                                <?php if ($_item->getIsSalable()): ?>
                                                    <div class="stock available"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('In stock') ?></span></div>
                                                <?php else: ?>
                                                    <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Out of stock') ?></span></div>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>

                                    <?php if ($showAddTo): ?>
                                        <div class="secondary-addto-links actions-secondary" data-role="add-to-links">
                                            <?php if ($addToBlock = $block->getChildBlock('addto')): ?>
                                                <?= $addToBlock->setProduct($_item)->getChildHtml() ?>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>-->
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                    <?= ($iterator == count($items)+1) ? '</div>' : '' ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                </div>               
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    requirejs(['jquery','Ves_All/lib/owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min'],function(jQuery,owlCarousel){
        (function($) {
            $(window).load(function () {
                $('#owlcarousel_<?=$type?>').owlCarousel({
                  autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds

                  items : 3,
                  nav: true,
                  navText: ["<i class='fa fa-angle-left' aria-hidden='true'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-angle-right' aria-hidden='true'></i>"],
                  itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
                  itemsDesktopSmall : [900,3], // betweem 900px and 601px
                  itemsTablet: [700,2], // 2 items between 600 and 480
                  itemsMobile : [479,1] , // 1 item between 479 and 0
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
    });
</script>   
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are using a custom theme name  **Vendor_customtheme**

You can follow the below steps to implement `OwlCarousel` Slider for `Related Product` in the product detail page.

**Note**: Below example describe `OwlCarousel` implementation for `Related Products` in the product detail page.

You need to update `app/design/frontend/Vendor/customtheme/Magento_Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml` file to implement `OwlCarousel` for `Related Products`.

**Step 1:** Download OwlCarousel from here: [Owl Carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/)

Please put all `OwlCarousel` JS files `owl.carousel.min.js` and `owlcarousel.js` in this directory `app/design/frontend/Vendor/customtheme/Magento_Catalog/web/js`

After that put all `OwlCarousel` CSS files `owl.carousel.css` and `owl.theme.default.css` etc... in this directory `app/design/frontend/Vendor/customtheme/web/css/owlcarousel/assets`

**Step 2:** Include `OwlCarousel` CSS files using `default_head_blocks.xml` layout XML file.

For that create `app/design/frontend/Vendor/customtheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml` file.

You can check **default_head_blocks.xml** file code as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>                
        <css src="css/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" />
        <css src="css/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

**Step 3:** Include `OwlCarousel` JS using `requirejs` config file.

For that create file `app/design/frontend/Vendor/customtheme/Magento_Catalog/requirejs-config.js` file.

You can check **requirejs-config.js** file code as below.

```
var config = {
    paths: {            
            'owlcarousel': "Magento_Catalog/js/owlcarousel"
        },   
    shim: {
        'owlcarousel': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

**Step 4:** Update `items.phtml` file.

Copy file `/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml` and paste here `app/design/frontend/Vendor/customtheme/Magento_Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml`

Now update the `item.phtml` file to implement `OwlCarousel`

You can check **items.phtml** file code as below.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/* @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct */
?>

<?php
switch ($type = $block->getType()) {

    case 'related-rule':
        if ($exist = $block->hasItems()) {
            $type = 'related';
            $class = $type;

            $image = 'related_products_list';
            $title = __('Related Products');
            $items = $block->getAllItems();
            $limit = $block->getPositionLimit();
            $shuffle = (int) $block->isShuffled();
            $canItemsAddToCart = $block->canItemsAddToCart();

            $showAddTo = false;
            $showCart = false;
            $templateType = null;
            $description = false;
        }
    break;

    case 'related':
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related $block */
        if ($exist = $block->getItems()->getSize()) {
            $type = 'related';
            $class = $type;

            $image = 'related_products_list';
            $title = __('Related Products');
            $items = $block->getItems();
            $limit = 0;
            $shuffle = 0;
            $canItemsAddToCart = $block->canItemsAddToCart();

            $showAddTo = true;
            $showCart = false;
            $templateType = null;
            $description = false;
        }
    break;

    case 'upsell-rule':
        if ($exist = $block->hasItems()) {
            $type = 'upsell';
            $class = $type;

            $image = 'upsell_products_list';
            $title = __('We found other products you might like!');
            $items = $block->getAllItems();
            $limit = $block->getPositionLimit();
            $shuffle = (int) $block->isShuffled();

            $showAddTo = false;
            $showCart = false;
            $templateType = null;
            $description = false;
            $canItemsAddToCart = false;
        }
    break;

    case 'upsell':
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Upsell $block */
        if ($exist = count($block->getItemCollection()->getItems())) {
            $type = 'upsell';
            $class = $type;

            $image = 'upsell_products_list';
            $title = __('You may also like');
            $items = $block->getItemCollection()->getItems();
            $limit = $block->getItemLimit('upsell');
            $shuffle = 0;

            $showAddTo = false;
            $showCart = false;
            $templateType = null;
            $description = false;
            $canItemsAddToCart = false;
        }
    break;

    case 'crosssell-rule':
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Crosssell $block */
        if ($exist = $block->hasItems()) {
            $type = 'crosssell';
            $class = $type;

            $image = 'cart_cross_sell_products';
            $title = __('More Choices:');
            $items = $block->getItemCollection();

            $showAddTo = true;
            $showCart = true;
            $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
            $description = false;
            $canItemsAddToCart = false;
        }
    break;

    case 'crosssell':
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Crosssell $block */
        if ($exist = count($block->getItems())) {
            $type = 'crosssell';
            $class = $type;

            $image = 'cart_cross_sell_products';
            $title = __('More Choices:');
            $items = $block->getItems();

            $showAddTo = true;
            $showCart = true;
            $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
            $description = false;
            $canItemsAddToCart = false;
        }
    break;

    case 'new':
        if ($exist = $block->getProductCollection()) {
            $type = 'new';
            $mode = 'grid';
            $type = $type . ' ' . $mode;

            $class = 'widget' . ' ' . $type;

            $image = 'new_products_content_widget_grid';
            $title = __('New Products');
            $items = $exist;

            $showAddTo = true;
            $showCart = true;
            $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
            $description = ($mode == 'list') ? true : false;
            $canItemsAddToCart = false;
        }
    break;

    case 'other':
    break;
}
?>

<?php if ($exist):?>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
    <?php if ($type == 'related' || $type == 'upsell'): ?>
        <?php if ($type == 'related'): ?>
            <div class="block <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $class ?>" data-mage-init='{"relatedProducts":{"relatedCheckbox":".related.checkbox"}}' data-limit="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $limit ?>" data-shuffle="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $shuffle ?>">
        <?php else: ?>
            <div class="block <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $class ?>" data-mage-init='{"upsellProducts":{}}' data-limit="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $limit ?>" data-shuffle="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $shuffle ?>">
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="block <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $class ?>">
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="block-title title">
        <strong id="block-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $class ?>-heading" role="heading" aria-level="2"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $title ?></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content content" aria-labelledby="block-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $class ?>-heading">
        <?php if ($type == 'related' && $canItemsAddToCart): ?>
        <div class="block-actions">
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Check items to add to the cart or') ?>
            <button type="button" class="action select" role="select-all"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('select all') ?></span></button>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="products wrapper grid products-grid products-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $type ?>">
            <div id="relateditem_carousel"  class="products list items product-items owl-carousel owl-theme">           
                <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
                <?php foreach ($items as $_item): ?>
                
                <?php $available = ''; ?>
                <?php if (!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable() && $type == 'related'): ?>
                    <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                        <?php $available = 'related-available'; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($type == 'related' || $type == 'upsell'): ?>
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ ($iterator++ == 1) ? '<div class="item product product-item" style="display: none;">' : '</div><div class="item product product-item" style="display: none;">' ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ ($iterator++ == 1) ? '<div class="item product product-item">' : '</div><div class="item product product-item">' ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="product-item-info <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $available ?>">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ '<!-- ' . $image . '-->' ?>
                    <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo">
                        <?= $block->getImage($_item, $image)->toHtml() ?>
                    </a>
                    <div class="product details product-item-details">
                        <!--<strong class="product name product-item-name"><a class="product-item-link" title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>">
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a>
                        </strong>-->

                        <!--<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($_item) ?>-->

                            <?php if ($templateType): ?>
                                <?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, $templateType) ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php if ($canItemsAddToCart && !$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable() && $type == 'related'): ?>
                                <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                                    <div class="field choice related">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox related" id="related-checkbox<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>" name="related_products[]" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>" />
                                        <label class="label" for="related-checkbox<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span></label>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php if ($showAddTo || $showCart): ?>
                                <div class="product actions product-item-actions">
                                    <?php if ($showCart): ?>
                                        <div class="actions-primary">
                                            <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                                                <?php if ($_item->getTypeInstance()->hasRequiredOptions($_item)): ?>
                                                    <button class="action tocart primary" data-mage-init='{"redirectUrl": {"url": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>"}}' type="button" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                                                        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                    </button>
                                                <?php else: ?>
                                                    <?php $postDataHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper');
                                                    $postData = $postDataHelper->getPostData($block->getAddToCartUrl($_item), ['product' => $_item->getEntityId()])
                                                    ?>
                                                    <button class="action tocart primary"
                                                            data-post='<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $postData ?>'
                                                            type="button" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                                                        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                    </button>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            <?php else: ?>
                                                <?php if ($_item->getIsSalable()): ?>
                                                    <div class="stock available"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('In stock') ?></span></div>
                                                <?php else: ?>
                                                    <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Out of stock') ?></span></div>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>

                                    <?php if ($showAddTo): ?>
                                        <div class="secondary-addto-links actions-secondary" data-role="add-to-links">
                                            <?php if ($addToBlock = $block->getChildBlock('addto')): ?>
                                                <?= $addToBlock->setProduct($_item)->getChildHtml() ?>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?= ($iterator == count($items)+1) ? '</div>' : '' ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                </div>               
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    requirejs(['jquery','owlcarousel'],function(jQuery,owlCarousel){
        (function($) {
            $(window).load(function () {
                $('#relateditem_carousel').owlCarousel({
                items:4,
                lazyLoad:false,
                loop:false,
                margin:10,
                nav:false,
                dots:false,
                autoplay:true,
                response:true,
                autoplayHoverPause:false,
                autoWidth:false,
                responsive : {
                    0 : {
                        items:1,
                    },
                    420 : {
                        items:2,
                    },
                    768 : {
                        items:3,
                    },
                    991 : {
                        items:4,
                    }
                }
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
    });
</script>   
<?php endif;?>
```

**Step 5:** Now run following CLI commands from your Magento root.

```
sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*
sudo rm -rf var/cache/*
```

[image]

Comment: What about upsell products? Will Upsell also show in slider after update this code?

Answer (score 0):

You can updates the file ***app/design/frontend/Vendor/customtheme/Magento_Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml*** to display both **Upsell Items**  and **Relates items**  as a slider in product detail page.

File : **items.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/* @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct */
?>
<?php
//    $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
//    $_product = $block->getProduct();
?>
<?php
switch ($type = $block->getType()) {

    case 'related-rule':
        if ($exist = $block->hasItems()) {
            $type = 'related';
            $class = $type;

            $image = 'related_products_list';
            $title = __('Related Products');
            $items = $block->getAllItems();
            $limit = $block->getPositionLimit();
            $shuffle = (int) $block->isShuffled();
            $canItemsAddToCart = $block->canItemsAddToCart();

            $showAddTo = true;
            $showCart = false;
            $templateType = null;
            $description = false;
        }
        break;

    case 'related':
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related $block */
        if ($exist = $block->getItems()->getSize()) {
            $type = 'related';
            $class = $type;

            $image = 'related_products_list';
            $title = __('Related Products');
            $items = $block->getItems();
            $limit = 0;
            $shuffle = 0;
            $canItemsAddToCart = $block->canItemsAddToCart();

            $showAddTo = true;
            $showCart = false;
            $templateType = null;
            $description = false;
        }
        break;

    case 'upsell-rule':
        if ($exist = $block->hasItems()) {
            $type = 'upsell';
            $class = $type;

            $image = 'upsell_products_list';
            $title = __('We found other products you might like!');
            $items = $block->getAllItems();
            $limit = $block->getPositionLimit();
            $shuffle = (int) $block->isShuffled();

            $showAddTo = false;
            $showCart = false;
            $templateType = null;
            $description = false;
            $canItemsAddToCart = false;
        }
        break;

    case 'upsell':
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Upsell $block */
        if ($exist = count($block->getItemCollection()->getItems())) {
            $type = 'upsell';
            $class = $type;

            $image = 'upsell_products_list';
            $title = __('We found other products you might like!');
            $items = $block->getItemCollection()->getItems();
            $limit = $block->getItemLimit('upsell');
            $shuffle = 0;

            $showAddTo = false;
            $showCart = false;
            $templateType = null;
            $description = false;
            $canItemsAddToCart = false;
        }
        break;

    case 'crosssell-rule':
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Crosssell $block */
        if ($exist = $block->hasItems()) {
            $type = 'crosssell';
            $class = $type;

            $image = 'cart_cross_sell_products';
            $title = __('More Choices:');
            $items = $block->getItemCollection();

            $showAddTo = true;
            $showCart = true;
            $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
            $description = false;
            $canItemsAddToCart = false;
        }
        break;

    case 'crosssell':
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Crosssell $block */
        if ($exist = count($block->getItems())) {
            $type = 'crosssell';
            $class = $type;

            $image = 'cart_cross_sell_products';
            $title = __('More Choices:');
            $items = $block->getItems();

            $showAddTo = true;
            $showCart = true;
            $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
            $description = false;
            $canItemsAddToCart = false;
        }
        break;

    case 'new':
        if ($exist = $block->getProductCollection()) {
            $type = 'new';
            $mode = 'grid';
            $type = $type . ' ' . $mode;

            $class = 'widget' . ' ' . $type;

            $image = 'new_products_content_widget_grid';
            $title = __('New Products');
            $items = $exist;

            $showAddTo = true;
            $showCart = true;
            $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
            $description = ($mode == 'list') ? true : false;
            $canItemsAddToCart = false;
        }
        break;

    default:
        $exist = null;
}
?>

<?php if ($exist): ?>
    <!--Start related products  Code-->
    <?php if ($type == 'related') { ?>
        <div class="block-title title">
            <strong id="block-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $class ?>-heading" role="heading" aria-level="2"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $title ?></strong>
        </div>          
        <div id="relateditem_carousel"  class="products list items product-items owl-carousel owl-theme">           
            <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
            <?php foreach ($items as $_item): ?>                
                <?php $available = ''; ?>
                <?php if (!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                        <?php $available = 'related-available'; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>               
                <div class="product-item-info <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $available ?>">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ '<!-- ' . $image . '-->' ?>
                    <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo">
                        <?= $block->getImage($_item, $image)->toHtml() ?>
                    </a>
                    <div class="product details product-item-details">
                        <strong class="product name product-item-name"><a class="product-item-link" title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>">
                                <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a>
                        </strong>
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($_item) ?>
                        <?php if ($templateType): ?>
                            <?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, $templateType) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php if ($canItemsAddToCart && !$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable() && $type == 'related'): ?>
                            <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                                <div class="field choice related">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox related" id="related-checkbox<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>" name="related_products[]" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>" />
                                    <label class="label" for="related-checkbox<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span></label>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php if ($showAddTo || $showCart): ?>
                            <div class="product actions product-item-actions">
                                <?php if ($showCart): ?>
                                    <div class="actions-primary">
                                        <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                                            <?php if ($_item->getTypeInstance()->hasRequiredOptions($_item)): ?>
                                                <button class="action tocart primary" data-mage-init='{"redirectUrl": {"url": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>"}}' type="button" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                                                    <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                </button>
                                            <?php else: ?>
                                                <?php
                                                $postDataHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper');
                                                $postData = $postDataHelper->getPostData($block->getAddToCartUrl($_item), ['product' => $_item->getEntityId()])
                                                ?>
                                                <button class="action tocart primary"
                                                        data-post='<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $postData ?>'
                                                        type="button" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                                                    <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                </button>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php else: ?>
                                            <?php if ($_item->getIsSalable()): ?>
                                                <div class="stock available"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('In stock') ?></span></div>
                                            <?php else: ?>
                                                <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Out of stock') ?></span></div>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <?php if ($showAddTo): ?>
                                    <div class="secondary-addto-links actions-secondary" data-role="add-to-links">
                                        <?php if ($addToBlock = $block->getChildBlock('addto')): ?>
                                            <?= $addToBlock->setProduct($_item)->getChildHtml() ?>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?= ($iterator == count($items) + 1) ? '</div>' : '' ?>
            <?php endforeach ?>        

        </div>

        <!--End related products  Code-->
    <?php } elseif ($type == 'upsell') { ?>    
        <!--Start upsell products  Code-->
        <div class="block-title title">
            <strong id="block-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $class ?>-heading" role="heading" aria-level="2"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $title ?> </strong>
        </div>
        <div id="upsellitem_carousel"  class="products list items product-items owl-carousel owl-theme">            
            <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
            <?php foreach ($items as $_item): ?>                
                <?php $available = ''; ?>                
                <div class="product-item-info <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $available ?>">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ '<!-- ' . $image . '-->' ?>
                    <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo">
                        <?= $block->getImage($_item, $image)->toHtml() ?>
                    </a>
                    <div class="product details product-item-details">
                        <strong class="product name product-item-name"><a class="product-item-link" title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>">
                                <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a>
                        </strong>
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($_item) ?>
                        <?php if ($templateType): ?>
                            <?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, $templateType) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php if ($canItemsAddToCart && !$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable() && $type == 'related'): ?>
                            <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                                <div class="field choice related">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox related" id="related-checkbox<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>" name="related_products[]" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>" />
                                    <label class="label" for="related-checkbox<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span></label>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php if ($showAddTo || $showCart): ?>
                            <div class="product actions product-item-actions">
                                <?php if ($showCart): ?>
                                    <div class="actions-primary">
                                        <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                                            <?php if ($_item->getTypeInstance()->hasRequiredOptions($_item)): ?>
                                                <button class="action tocart primary" data-mage-init='{"redirectUrl": {"url": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>"}}' type="button" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                                                    <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                </button>
                                            <?php else: ?>
                                                <?php
                                                $postDataHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper');
                                                $postData = $postDataHelper->getPostData($block->getAddToCartUrl($_item), ['product' => $_item->getEntityId()])
                                                ?>
                                                <button class="action tocart primary"
                                                        data-post='<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $postData ?>'
                                                        type="button" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                                                    <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                </button>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php else: ?>
                                            <?php if ($_item->getIsSalable()): ?>
                                                <div class="stock available"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('In stock') ?></span></div>
                                            <?php else: ?>
                                                <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Out of stock') ?></span></div>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                    <?php if ($showAddTo): ?>
                                    <div class="secondary-addto-links actions-secondary" data-role="add-to-links">
                                        <?php if ($addToBlock = $block->getChildBlock('addto')): ?>
                                            <?= $addToBlock->setProduct($_item)->getChildHtml() ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?= ($iterator == count($items) + 1) ? '</div>' : '' ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        </div>
        <!--End upsell products  Code-->
    <?php } else { ?>                 
        <!--Start crosssell products  Code-->
        <div class="block <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $class ?>">
            <div class="block-title title">
                <strong id="block-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $class ?>-heading" role="heading" aria-level="2"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $title ?></strong>
            </div>
            <div class="block-content content" aria-labelledby="block-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $class ?>-heading">

                <div class="products wrapper grid products-grid products-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $type ?>">
                    <ol class="products list items product-items">
                        <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
                        <?php foreach ($items as $_item): ?>
                            <?php $available = ''; ?>
                            <?php if (!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable() && $type == 'related'): ?>
                                <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                                    <?php $available = 'related-available'; ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if ($type == 'related' || $type == 'upsell'): ?>
                                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ ($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="item product product-item" style="display: none;">' : '</li><li class="item product product-item" style="display: none;">' ?>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ ($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="item product product-item">' : '</li><li class="item product product-item">' ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <div class="product-item-info <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $available ?>">
                                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ '<!-- ' . $image . '-->' ?>
                                <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo">
            <?= $block->getImage($_item, $image)->toHtml() ?>
                                </a>
                                <div class="product details product-item-details">
                                    <strong class="product name product-item-name"><a class="product-item-link" title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>">
            <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a>
                                    </strong>

                                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($_item) ?>

                                    <?php if ($templateType): ?>
                                        <?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, $templateType) ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>

                                    <?php if ($canItemsAddToCart && !$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable() && $type == 'related'): ?>
                <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                                            <div class="field choice related">
                                                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox related" id="related-checkbox<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>" name="related_products[]" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>" />
                                                <label class="label" for="related-checkbox<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span></label>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>

                                        <?php if ($showAddTo || $showCart): ?>
                                        <div class="product actions product-item-actions">
                                                <?php if ($showCart): ?>
                                                <div class="actions-primary">
                                                    <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <?php if ($_item->getTypeInstance()->hasRequiredOptions($_item)): ?>
                                                            <button class="action tocart primary" data-mage-init='{"redirectUrl": {"url": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>"}}' type="button" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                                                                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                            </button>
                                                        <?php else: ?>
                                                            <?php
                                                            $postDataHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper');
                                                            $postData = $postDataHelper->getPostData($block->getAddToCartUrl($_item), ['product' => $_item->getEntityId()])
                                                            ?>
                                                            <button class="action tocart primary"
                                                                    data-post='<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $postData ?>'
                                                                    type="button" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                                                                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                            </button>
                                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                                    <?php else: ?>
                                                        <?php if ($_item->getIsSalable()): ?>
                                                            <div class="stock available"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('In stock') ?></span></div>
                                                        <?php else: ?>
                                                            <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Out of stock') ?></span></div>
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                                </div>
                                            <?php endif; ?>

                                                <?php if ($showAddTo): ?>
                                                <div class="secondary-addto-links actions-secondary" data-role="add-to-links">
                                                    <?php if ($addToBlock = $block->getChildBlock('addto')): ?>
                                                    <?= $addToBlock->setProduct($_item)->getChildHtml() ?>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                                </div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                        </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
            <?= ($iterator == count($items) + 1) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--End crosssell products  Code-->    
    <?php } ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        requirejs(['jquery', 'owlcarousel'], function (jQuery, owlCarousel) {
            (function ($) {
                $(window).load(function () {
                    //init Related Product owl carousel
                    $('#relateditem_carousel').owlCarousel({
                        items: 4,
                        lazyLoad: false,
                        loop: false,
                        margin: 10,
                        nav: false,
                        dots: false,
                        autoplay: true,
                        response: true,
                        autoplayHoverPause: false,
                        autoWidth: false,
                        responsive: {
                            0: {
                                items: 1,
                            },
                            420: {
                                items: 2,
                            },
                            768: {
                                items: 3,
                            },
                            991: {
                                items: 4,
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    //init Upsell Product owl carousel
                    $('#upsellitem_carousel').owlCarousel({
                        items: 4,
                        lazyLoad: false,
                        loop: false,
                        margin: 10,
                        nav: false,
                        dots: false,
                        autoplay: true,
                        response: true,
                        autoplayHoverPause: false,
                        autoWidth: false,
                        responsive: {
                            0: {
                                items: 1,
                            },
                            420: {
                                items: 2,
                            },
                            768: {
                                items: 3,
                            },
                            991: {
                                items: 4,
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            })(jQuery);
        });
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help.I have done this task.I just put carousel id dynamically using $type check.

Comment: No need to use all code within else condition.

Comment: I wanna add cross sell in product detailed page with slider, But in my code there already has the related and upsell product in slider using some customization of upsell-products.js and related-products.js, the above code will help me to add the slider for the cross sell product ?